# How to programmatically generate a dataset object from the Cartesian product (aka "cross-join") of multiple one-dimensional cell arrays?

Tags: matlab, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have *n* cell arrays *c*<sub>1</sub>,*c*<sub>2</sub>,…,*c*<sub>*n*</sub>, having dimensions *L*<sub>1</sub> × 1,*L*<sub>2</sub> × 1,…, *L*<sub>*n*</sub> × 1, respectively.  (FWIW, each cell array contains elements of a unique class, but this class may not be the same for all the arrays.)

I want to produce a `dataset` object representing the Cartesian product (aka "cross-join") of these *n* cell arrays.

> I'm looking for a *programmatic* way to do this that will work for any *n*.

To be clear about what I mean by "Cartesian product" (or "cross-join"): I want to produce a dataset object containing *n* columns and *L*<sub>1</sub> × *L*<sub>2</sub> × … ×*L*<sub>*n*</sub> rows, one row for each possible combination of an entry from *c*<sub>1</sub>, an entry from *c*<sub>2</sub>, …, an entry from *c*<sub>*n* - 1</sub>, and an entry from *c*<sub>*n*</sub>.  (It's OK to assume that none of *c*<sub>1</sub>,*c*<sub>2</sub>,…,*c*<sub>*n*</sub> contains duplicate entries.  IOW, one may assume that every *c<sub>i</sub>* is equal to `unique(`*c<sub>i</sub>*`)`.)

---

An example where *n* = 3 is given below; the desired result is the `dataset` object `factors`.  (Of course, the names of `factors`'s columns represent an additional parameter.  Also, in this example, all the cell arrays contain strings, but, as already mentioned, in general, the different arrays will contain entries of different classes.)

```
>> c1

c1 = 

    'even'
    'odd'

>> c2

c2 = 

    'green'
    'red'
    'yellow'

>> c3

c3 = 

    'clubs'
    'diamonds'
    'hearts'
    'spades'

>> factors

factors = 

    Parity        TrafficLight    Suit          
    'even'        'red'           'spades'      
    'even'        'red'           'hearts'      
    'even'        'red'           'diamonds'    
    'even'        'red'           'clubs'       
    'even'        'yellow'        'spades'      
    'even'        'yellow'        'hearts'      
    'even'        'yellow'        'diamonds'    
    'even'        'yellow'        'clubs'       
    'even'        'green'         'spades'      
    'even'        'green'         'hearts'      
    'even'        'green'         'diamonds'    
    'even'        'green'         'clubs'       
    'odd'         'red'           'spades'      
    'odd'         'red'           'hearts'      
    'odd'         'red'           'diamonds'    
    'odd'         'red'           'clubs'       
    'odd'         'yellow'        'spades'      
    'odd'         'yellow'        'hearts'      
    'odd'         'yellow'        'diamonds'    
    'odd'         'yellow'        'clubs'       
    'odd'         'green'         'spades'      
    'odd'         'green'         'hearts'      
    'odd'         'green'         'diamonds'    
    'odd'         'green'         'clubs'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for

- arbitrary number of cell arrays, *n*;
- arbitrary size of each cell array;
- arbitrary type of each cell's contents.

It makes use of [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b). The Cartesian product is computed on indices (not on actual elements) using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html), with [`fliplr`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) to yield the order you want (first column varies slowest, last column varies fastest).

The result is given as a cell array with *n* columns. If you need it in the form of a dataset, define appropriate names and use [`cell2dataset`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/cell2dataset.html) to convert.

```
c1 = {'even','odd'}; %// example data
c2 = {'green','red','yellow'};
c3 = {'clubs','diamonds','hearts','spades'};
sets = {c1, c2, c3}; %// can have an arbirary number of c's

num = numel(sets);
nums = cellfun(@(c) numel(c), sets);
inds = cell(1,num);
vec = fliplr(arrayfun(@(n) 1:n, nums, 'uni', 0));
[inds{:}] = ndgrid(vec{:});
inds = fliplr(inds);
factors = arrayfun(@(n) {sets{n}{inds{n}}},1:num, 'uni', 0);
factors = cat(1, factors{:}).';
```

Result:

```
>> factors
factors = 
    'even'    'green'     'clubs'   
    'even'    'green'     'diamonds'
    'even'    'green'     'hearts'  
    'even'    'green'     'spades'  
    'even'    'red'       'clubs'   
    'even'    'red'       'diamonds'
    'even'    'red'       'hearts'  
    'even'    'red'       'spades'  
    'even'    'yellow'    'clubs'   
    'even'    'yellow'    'diamonds'
    'even'    'yellow'    'hearts'  
    'even'    'yellow'    'spades'  
    'odd'     'green'     'clubs'   
    'odd'     'green'     'diamonds'
    'odd'     'green'     'hearts'  
    'odd'     'green'     'spades'  
    'odd'     'red'       'clubs'   
    'odd'     'red'       'diamonds'
    'odd'     'red'       'hearts'  
    'odd'     'red'       'spades'  
    'odd'     'yellow'    'clubs'   
    'odd'     'yellow'    'diamonds'
    'odd'     'yellow'    'hearts'  
    'odd'     'yellow'    'spades'
```

Answer (score 2):

This was fun to think about - here's what I came up with:

```
function product = setjoin(sets, names)
product = {};
nrows = 1;
for curset=sets(:)'
    curset = curset{1}(:);
    n = length(curset);
    setidx = repmat(1:n, nrows, 1)(:);
    product = [repmat(product, n, 1) curset(setidx)];
    nrows = nrows * n;
end
product = cell2dataset([names(:)'; product]);
end
```

where `sets` is a cell array of cell arrays `{c1, c2,..., cn}` and `names` is a cell array of strings. As is it's a bit hacky - this method of coercing things into row/column vectors where required is concise but isn't necessarily obvious, especially in generating `setidx` - but hopefully it gives you an idea to build upon.